# Exclude some Roles from list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Seems quite simple idea, but I'm having doubts so if possible to help me clear it up.

There's a list of Roles in my application, and for certain Roles (different kinds of admins) I'd like to show or hide certain Roles.

For example, if there are superadmin, admin, and user. super admin can manage all roles but he shouldn't be able to mess with the three i mentioned. So I want them out of the list.

List in view is generated with `foreach` loop, so I though of changing class of the container if the value that will be presented is one of the three (superadmin, admin, or user). Will that work?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood you correctly but it would be better not to show the container directly (don't print it to the output) from the server instead of relying on CSS to hide them.

Comment: You seem to have understood. But how would I then separate those three `Roles` from others? Maybe add a `string` prefix, and then filter using LINQ, and `.Contain("prefix")` ???

Comment: Or store them in a table on your DB. You could then have a correspondence on which roles can "see" which other roles...

Comment: Hmmmm, maybe a stupid question, but how would that table look like?
`ID`, `RoleID` only? Note that I'm using EF Code first and it gets kind of tricky around that part since I don't really understand how to create a model that is connected with existing membership database...

Comment: You can have something like `role`,`viewablerole`. You can look for every role if your user has a role that is allowed to see it.